# Yeoman and handlebars templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, yeoman

Is anybody using yeoman with ember?

If so, how do I get yeoman to compile the handlebars templates?

If possible I would like to use the rake pipeline.

Has anyone come up with a solution to compile the handlebars templates from yeoman?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dan Gebhardt has been working on getting Ember handlebars compilation working with yeoman. You can see the fruits of his efforts here: https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates

Comment: is this still the best way to approach the issue? there's so much change on yeoman/emberjs right now, it's hard to tell.

Comment: According to Dan: "yeah, but stick to v0.2.0 for yeoman, which still relies on grunt 0.3. the latest grunt-ember-templates is v0.4, which is grunt 0.4 compatible"